# Existence of connected neighborhood in product via projection

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, geometric-topology

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a space, a neighborhood of a subset $A$ of $X$ is a set $N$ containing an open set (in $X$) that contains $A$.

That is, a neighborhood need not be open.

---

Assume $Y'$ is a locally compact, $T_2$ space and that $X$ is locally connected.

Consider a continuous map $f:X \times Y\rightarrow X\times Y'$. Assume

(1). $\pi_1(f(x,y))=x$ for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. Where $\pi_1:X\times Y'\rightarrow X$ is the projection map.

(2). Further assume that for each $x\in X$, the map $\varphi_x:Y\rightarrow Y'$, given by $\varphi_x(y)=\pi_2(f(x,y))$, is an open map that is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Here  $\pi_2: X\times Y'\rightarrow Y'$  is the projection map.

Further assume $(a,x)\in X\times U$, where $U$ is a precompact open subset of $x$ in $Y$

Note, $U$ is locally compact and Hausdorff $(\star)$

As $U$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, we can find precompact $V\owns x$ in $U$. Since $V$ is locally compact, we can find a precompact $W\owns x$ in $V$. Then, $\overline{W}\subseteq int(\overline{V})$.

**Lemma:** There exists a connected neighborhood $N_a$ of $a$ in $X$ such that for all $b\in N_a$, $\varphi_b(\overline{W})\subseteq \varphi_{a}(int(\overline{V}))$.

I am unable to prove the Lemma.

**Comments:**

[1]I tried looking the the fact that $f^{-1}(a \times \varphi_a(\overline{W}))$ is closed and contained in $X\times \overline{W}$ (by $(1)$). However, I have gotten nowhere.

[2]. $\star$ follows from the fact that each $\phi_{x}$ is a homeomorphism onto image.

[3]. $Y$ is Hausdorff and locally compact since $\phi_{x}$ is a homeomorphism onto image and is open.

[4]. We need to find  connected $N_a$ of $a$ such that for all $b\in N_a$,  $\overline{W}\subseteq \phi_{b}^{-1}(\phi_{a}(int(\overline{V}))$.

Comment: "open subset of x in F??What is F?

Comment: @giorgiokyn23 fixed. sorry

Comment: There is some confusion here $\varphi_x:Y\rightarrow Y'$, given by $\varphi_x(y)=\pi_2(f(x,y))$, is an open map that is a homeomorphism onto its image.

Here  $\pi_2: X\times Y'\rightarrow Y$  is the projection map.
 $\phi_x $ and \pi_2$$ have not the same codomain

Comment: @giorgiokyn23 It's a typo. I meant $\pi_2:X\times Y'\rightarrow Y'$, obviously

Comment: yeah but to be sure I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$, hence we can replace it by its interior and simply suppose $V$ is open. Then $V\subset$int$(\overline V)$ and we seek the inclusion $\varphi_b(\overline W)\subset\varphi_a(V)$.
Then
$\varphi_a(V)$ is open in $Y'$ and $f^{-1}(X\times\varphi_a(V))$ is open in $X\times Y$. Since
$$
\{a\}\times\overline W\subset f^{-1}(X\times\varphi_a(V)),
$$
and the latter set is open neighborhood in $X\times Y$ of the compact set
$\{a\}\times\overline W$. By the general tube lemma, there is an open neighborhood $A$ of $a$ such that
$$
A\times\overline W\subset f^{-1}(X\times\varphi_a(V)).
$$
This implies that for every $b\in A$ the condition we seek holds. But $X$ is locally connected, and we can choose a smaller connected $A$.

Comment: You're invoking the Tube Lemma. Doesn't that require $X$ to be compact?

Comment: The compactness needed is that of the subspaces whose product is analised, not the ambient spaces where the product is made.